# css transition changing class with pseudoelement

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions

I am working on a React app.

I am using two css classes with after pseudo-element to add a right- and a down- triangle

```
   .triangle-right::after {
        content: "\25B6";
        font-size: 10px;
    }
    .triangle-down::after {
        content: "\25BC";
        font-size: 10px;
    }
```

I transition from the two triangles changing the class of the element.

```
<span className={(this.state.isOpen ? 'triangle-down' : 'triangle-right')}></span>
```

Is it possible to use css transition to animate the change ?

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/cladev/pen/OvMjze?editors=0010)

Comment: You can only animate things for which the intermediate state is calculable.  Halfway between 0 and 1 is 0.5.   Halfway between `"\25B6"` and `"\25BC"` is...

Comment: ...and you can't transition the "content" property either. Why not use the same symbol and rotate it?

Comment: https://codepen.io/cladev/pen/wmMrvM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but not like you've done it. Try this:

```
.triangle-right:after {
    content: "\25B6";
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 10px;
    transition: transform 200ms;
}
.triangle-right.is-open:after {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

and this html

```
<span className={`triangle-right${this.state.isOpen ? ' is-open' : ''}`} />
```

What this does is rotate the original icon, instead of changing it to a new one (which isn't possible to animate with a font).

[See it working in this demo.](https://codepen.io/zeroskillz/pen/mxVBbN)